# Uncaught TypeError: this.d3.set is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, c3.js

Following the example on https://c3js.org/gettingstarted.html I ran into above mentioned error. I have set up `php -S localhost:8000`. Then I open this .html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>C3 Example</title>

<!-- Load c3.css -->
<link href="c3/c3.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Load d3.js and c3.js -->
<script src="d3/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="c3/c3.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
      ],
      axes: {
        data2: 'y2' // ADD
      }
    },
    axis: {
      y2: {
        show: true // ADD
      }
    }
});
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong here? All I did was copypasting the codesample.

Comment: Which version of d3 did you use in this example? If you are unsure, you can use `console.log(d3.version)` to check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you have downloaded the latest version of both `c3` and `d3`, but the latest version of the `c3` library is requiring `v5` of the `d3` library, it is not compatible with the newest version (`v6`) yet.

So, just downgrade your `d3` version to `v5.16.0` and it should be good.
Here is your code with just the sources updated to the currently latest `c3` (`v0.7.20`) and `v5.16.0` of `d3`, tested, seems to work without issues.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>C3 Example</title>

    <!-- Load c3.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.20/c3.min.css" integrity="sha512-cznfNokevSG7QPA5dZepud8taylLdvgr0lDqw/FEZIhluFsSwyvS81CMnRdrNSKwbsmc43LtRd2/WMQV+Z85AQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

    <!-- Load d3.js and c3.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-FHsFVKQ/T1KWJDGSbrUhTJyS1ph3eRrxI228ND0EGaEp6v4a/vGwPWd3Dtd/+9cI7ccofZvl/wulICEurHN1pg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.20/c3.min.js" integrity="sha512-+IpCthlNahOuERYUSnKFjzjdKXIbJ/7Dd6xvUp+7bEw0Jp2dg6tluyxLs+zq9BMzZgrLv8886T4cBSqnKiVgUw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
      ],
      axes: {
        data2: 'y2' // ADD
      }
    },
    axis: {
      y2: {
        show: true // ADD
      }
    }
});
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Istvan! Coming fresh to the c3js website I was struggling to determine the best d3 version to use. I poked around in `package.json` where I see it says `"d3": "^5.8.0"`. My first guess was that this meant anything later than 5.8, so I went ahead and just tried the current v7, hence ending up here. So I suppose "^5.8.0" means 5.8 or later within the v5 major version.

Answer (score 0):

in the example you provided it is `<script src="/path/to/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>` but you are missing `v5` on your own code. Check in "Network" tab of your browser if your d3 library is loaded or if your browser fails to find the file because of this filename difference. If so, fix the filename

Comment: I renamed 'd3.min.js' to 'd3.v5.min.js' in the folders as well as in the source code. Still the same error occurs.

Comment: @schmark it doesn't really matter if the filename includes `v5` or not. I only pointed it in case you had a wrong filename and the browser totally failed to find and load the file.